# How to safely generate and store a password out of Google OAuth user data for a REST API

Tags: rest, security, google-oauth, passport.js, password-protection

I have a web app, where users sign in with Google (OAuth 2.0).
This web app uses a REST API (figo.io) in the background, so I have to create an API user with credentials.

Now I have the following problem: I have to generate a username and a password out of nowhere. The username is trivial, but the password...

Since my users log in with Google, I don't know their password, and I don't want to ask them for an additional password for the sake of a better UX. The only thing I have is their Google+ profile data.

So how do I generate this REST API password and store it safely? In their [docs](http://docs.figo.io/#user-management), the API developers state:

> **ONE FIGO USER PER APPLICATION USER**
>   [...]
>   In this scenario it is recommend to create the figo users with a username directly mappable from your application user IDs, e.g. using [your user ID]@figo.[you application domain]. That way you do not have to save any additional information and still do not block email address of your user for explicit figo usage. **Some similar, but more secure, mapping is recommended for the users password**.

I can't think of a *secure* way to achieve this last bit about the password.

So far, the best solution I came up with is to use my users UUID (a hash), and the Google ID (from their profile, it's an int) and hash those two values into a password.

But if an attacker would hack my database, he would know the google id as well as the uuid...

Does anyone of you have a great idea? Or is "hacking my database" not a problem I should care about? I should say, that the figo API is used for online banking, so I really want the users' data to be secure.

P.S.:
Just FYI, I use a node/express server in this web app.
I use passport for Google OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [JWT token](https://jwt.io/) as a identifier and keep it stateless.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I don't see how this is gonna help me generating a password for another API.